# What password to store in database when user registers through OAuth2 (Example: google or facebook)?

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

I have a Web Application that permits user to register though a normal HTML Form, or via Facebook or Google. 
The question is what password should I store in the database, because even if the OAuth provider gives me relevant information like email, name, age, etc... It **Obviously** does not give you a password.
What would be the correct password to store in Database?
I have a few ideas:

1. Generate a Random one and send it through email (Not very secure)
2. Add an empty string. (They will never be able to login using a password because on acceptin login request I validate that password should contain more than 5 characters, this sounds like a very hacky way to do it)
3. Make it compulsory to fill in a password after registering through OAuth provider.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your application. Is authentication going to run specifically through a 3rd party - i.e. googleAuth?

If it is, there is no need to store a password. If you would also like to handle authentication in your application then give a user an option to sign up with google/facebook or with your application.

I see 3rd party authentication as a better user experience because they don't have to register on another site. With that in mind, if they sign up on your site then require a password, if they choose a 3rd party authentication, don't store a password.

Comment: They can either authenticate though 3rd Party or though the apps own Authentication system. So you could login through google or login:password (Same account also)

Comment: Is that forced - so for example if I signed in with google would you also want me to create an application specific account with username & password?

Comment: No, I just want them to have both options available. Imagine, I am using my friend's computer, I normally login through google but my friend's computer is logged into his account. In this case I would login through email+password instead of going around all the trouble of logginf out of google and login back in again just so i can login.